# Portal inside Fragments?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Is it possible to use `ReactDOM.createPortal` inside `<React.Fragment>` with another element that is rendered to where the component is rendered or am I doing something wrong here?

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                ReactDOM.createPortal(<h1>Hello</h1>, 
                                      document.getElementById('side'))
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is entirely possible, you just  need to wrap `React.createPortal` within `{}` like

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {ReactDOM.createPortal(<h1>Hello</h1>, 
                                      document.getElementById('side'))}
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

**[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmjzzlw80j)**

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem, I'm wondering why this isn't mentioned in the official documentation at https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html.